# providing password to ssh

Tags: ssh, password

The situation:

- I have an IP : 192.168.1.1 `$IP`
- username : root (or whatever) `$USER`
- and a passwd: foo `$PASSWD`

Is there a way to give $PASSWD to ssh ? like

```
 PASSWORD_VAR=$PASSWD ssh -l $USER $IP
```

- user can see the password,
- user must "land" on usual interactive shell session.
- somme package might be installed on desktop linux if need be.

reading ssh(1) give me no clues. such thing exists in window's world (e.g. Kitty), now I would like to do the same in unix (suse or unbuntu if that matter).

I know how to set up public/private key pair, but this is off topic.

Comment: there is also a more complete answer here : http://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password , unfortunatly I didn't see it before posting, neither do I notice U&L's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible if you can install [sshpass](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass), so you can run:

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh 192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 2):

`ssh` by default and by design doesn't do it. This is because clear text passwords embedded in scripts is pretty fundamentally a bad idea. Not least because - if it's specified on a single command line, it *normally* shows up in the `ps` list that every user can see. 
So it's deliberately made difficult, to encourage better habits. public-private key pairs and `ssh-agent` go a long way to removing the requirement.

If you've really a need, then `expect` can do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn /usr/bin/ssh -n username@hostname 
expect "password:"
send "Password\n";
interact
```

(Or `sshpass` as the other commentator has mentioned).